# is "compute a curve" a clear and appropriate expression?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

i am asking a question on this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3241453/649828), here is the key part of the question

> i am trying to compute a space-filling curve for a given shape (an
>   isosceles right triangle in this case) like following figure (call it
>   figure_1)

is it clear and appropriate by saying `compute a curve`.

Answer (score 1):

> to compute a curve

is a correct statement.

However, you should not associate "triangle" and "space-filling"

A better sentence could be:

> **I** am trying to compute **an** **area**-filling curve for a given shape (an isosceles right triangle in this case) like **in the** following figure (call it figure_1)